# GPO Office 2013 Protected View - Unsafe Locations - Blocking Files

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-excel

I am attempting to force all Excel files in the `R:\Folder` network map to open in protected view.

I set up the GPO and added the path to `Unsafe Location #1`

**GPO Policy:**  `User Config -> Admin Templates -> MS Office 2013 -> Security Settings -> Trust Center -> Protected View`

Whenever a user attempted to open a spreadsheet via our CRM, from that location, Excel would complain that it did not have enough free space to open the file.

Once I removed the `Unsafe Location #1` from the GPO it immediately opened the file in edit mode.

It seems that the `Protected View` setting isn't working correctly with the `Unsafe Locations`.